# ¿Cómo activo https?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, https, server

Espero que alguien me responda, es mi primera vez aquí. Estoy haciendo una cosa en mi servidor respecto al https y me he fijado que esta inactivo `systemctl is-active https`, he probado con `systemctl start https` y `systemctl enable https` pero me indica que no es un servicio, he mirado por internet y no sale nada de información, si alguien pudiera decirme cómo puedo activar https se lo agradecería.

Comment: Explicanos un poco sobre esa "cosa" que estas haciendo y por la cual necesitas utilizar https, seria mas facil ayudarte si tenemos una vision mas amplia del problema.

Comment: Debes instalar un certificado SSL para ello. Para que podamos ayudarte sería bueno que nos digas en qué plataforma está montado tu servidor y de qué software es. Digamos, Apache, NGINX, Cherokee, Lighttpd, etc.

Comment: Es un servidor Ubuntu 18.04 el cual estoy utilizando Apache, estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual tengo que hacer una página moodle (que ya está creada), también tengo creado el certificado SSL y las claves. Llevo varios días intentado hacer una redirección de http a https, he probado de varias formas con el .htaccess y con el archivo de configuración del sitio y ssl.conf, pero nada da resultado, hoy he visto que no tenía activo el https e igual es ese el problema el cual no me funciona el redireccionamiento.

Comment: Hola Silvia. Por favor si la respuesta te fue util aceptala. En caso contrario facilítame más información para que pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero de todo que tienes que hacer es ver si tienes el módulo de SSL instalado.

Sin ese módulo, tu servidor Apache no tendrá la opción de poder servir nada bajo HTTPS.

Eso lo puedes ver con el siguiente comando:

```
apache2ctl -M | grep ssl
```

La respuesta debería de ser:

```
root@xxx:~# apache2ctl -M | grep ssl
 ssl_module (shared)
```

Si no te sale nada, con hacer un `a2enmod ssl` debería de valer, ya que por defecto en Ubuntu existe el módulo pero puede que no esté activo.

Si has tenido que activarlo, reinicia Apache para que surta efecto.

Una vez tengas eso, lo que tienes que hacer es modificar el VirtualHost que tienes creado en `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/` que es donde habrás configurado el dominio de tu moodle.

Lo más normal es cambiar el puerto 80(http) por el 443(https) y añadir la siguientes líneas:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile      /ruta/al/certificado.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /ruta/al/certificado/intermedio.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /ruta/a/la/key.key
```

Como veras las rutas son de ejemplo, puedes ponerlo en el sitio que quieras. Yo generalmente pongo los certificados en `/etc/ssl/certs/`

Luego para hacer las redirecciones lo puedes hacer creando un VirtualHost que haga de `301` por ejemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName midominio.com

    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 / http://midominio.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya me funciona. Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: Hola @Silvia si te funciona gracias a mi respuesta, por favor marca mi respuesta como válida. Aquí tienes como aceptar una respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas